# Redirect users to Long URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-routing, redirect

I have an application where URL after rewriting are like this

> http://www.domain.com/product/seller/product_id

an example link would be

> http://storeiown.com/product/kitchenking/92013

This was okay but I need the title of the product to be included in the url

> http://storeiown.com/product/a-very-nice-electric-cooker-by-kitchenking/92013

I achieved this too and all was good.

Now, I want all the url which do not include the title to redirect to this one. 
Like, if user lands from the url without the title they should be redirected to a version of the page with the url containing the title in the url.

How do i accomplish that. And for info additional info I use CodeIgniter in the app, if that makes it any easier.

Comment: Would mod_rewrite not work? Also you should consider separating the product name from the brand, like `http://storeiown.com/product/kitchenking/a-very-nice-electric-cooker/92013` as having all info in one chunk reduces usefulness both for indexing and user experience.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way which i use. In the previous page type this at the top:-

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['mainpass']= '0';
?>
```

And in the next page code this at the top of the page :-

```
<?php
session_start;
if(isset($_SESSION['mainpass'])) {
//run the current page
}else{
header("location: www.domain.com");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codeigniter, you could try the below.

```
$seg3 = $this->uri->segment(3);
if(is_numeric($seg3)){
//The user has come without the header because the third segment is numeric thus probably using the product id. 
//Therefore, redirect again to the proper link after getting the heading from your db
} else {
// do nothing
// the seg3 is not numeric means it probably came through normal preferred way
}
```

And in order to use the

```
$this->uri->segment(3);
```

You need to  either

- auto load the url helper
- load manually when required